# Cooking a 5 pound pork sirloin roast

Tags: pork

Put a 5 pound pork sirloin roast in oven at 175 degrees F for two hours. Then turned up oven to 350F for two hours. Is it safe to eat?

Comment: What does your thermometer say?

Comment: There is no way for us to tell you that your food is safe to consume... only you can tell by using a thermometer and comparing that internal temperature to the "safe" temperatures chart.

Comment: It's more about internal temperature than it is about the time and temp. Can't really help you.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to tell if a pork roast has been cooked long enough is by taking an internal temperature with an instant-read thermometer in several places around the *thickest* portion of the roast.

> The National Pork Board recommends cooking pork chops, roasts, and tenderloin to an internal temperature between 145° F. (medium rare) and 160° F. (medium), followed by a 3 minute rest. Since large cuts increase approximately 10° F while resting, remove them from the heat at 150° F. followed by a 10 minute rest.
>
> [Pork Cooking Times and Temperatures](http://www.porkbeinspired.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/2924.pdf)